# Why does the result of the ADFGVX encryption algorithm produce a different result than the wikipedia example?

Tags: python, cryptography

I'm having trouble writing the algorithm. I must say right away that the basis was not written from scratch, I found several examples of the implementation of this algorithm and used them.

As a test of the result of the work, I used an example from Wikipedia:

message - ***attack at 1200am***

key - ***privacy***

The output I get is: **GVVA DAVF GFVF AAGF AADV DDGA AAVA**

When the encryption result from wikipedia is: **DGDD DAGD DGAF ADDF DADV DVFA ADVX**

Here is the code, help please

```
from re import findall

# keys
keys_dictionary = {
 'A': 'AA', 'N': 'FD', '0': 'VF',
 'B': 'AD', 'O': 'FF', '1': 'VG',
 'C': 'AF', 'P': 'FG', '2': 'VV',
 'D': 'AG', 'Q': 'FV', '3': 'VX',
 'E': 'AV', 'R': 'FX', '4': 'XA',
 'F': 'AX', 'S': 'GA', '5': 'XD',
 'G': 'DA', 'T': 'GD', '6': 'XF',
 'H': 'DD', 'U': 'GF', '7': 'XG',
 'I': 'DF', 'V': 'GG', '8': 'XV',
 'J': 'DG', 'W': 'GV', '9': 'XX',
 'K': 'DV', 'X': 'GX',
 'L': 'DX', 'Y': 'VA',
 'M': 'FA', 'Z': 'VD',
}

def crypt_menu():
    crypt_mode = input("Enter mode: [E]crypt || [D]ecrypt: ").upper()
    if crypt_mode not in ['E', 'D']:  # check mode
        print("\ERROR! Mode not found! Try again...")
        raise SystemExit

    return crypt_mode


input_text = input("Enter text: ").upper()
key = input("Enter key: ").upper()


def regular(text):
    template = r"[A-Z]{2}"

    return findall(template, text)


# stage one
def stage_one(mode, message, final=""):
    if mode == 'E':
        for symbol in message:
            if symbol in keys_dictionary:
                final += keys_dictionary[symbol]

    else:
        for symbols in regular(message):
            for i in keys_dictionary:
                if symbols == keys_dictionary[i]:
                    final += i

    return final


# stage two
def stage_two(mode, message, final=""):
    if mode == 'E':
        while len(message) % len(key) != 0:
            message += 'XX'

        length_list = len(message) // len(key)
        list_cut_words = []

        for _ in range(length_list):
            list_cut_words.append([])

        index = 0
        counter = 1

        for symbol in message:
            if counter % len(key) != 0:
                list_cut_words[index].append(symbol)
                counter += 1

            else:
                list_cut_words[index].append(symbol)
                index += 1
                counter = 1

        keys = {x: [] for x in key}

        index = 0

        for i in key:
            for x in range(len(list_cut_words)):
                keys[i].append(list_cut_words[x][index])
            index += 1

        key_sort = list(key)
        key_sort.sort()

        keys = {i: keys[i] for i in key_sort if i in keys}

        for list_symbol in keys:
            for symbol in keys[list_symbol]:
                final += symbol

    else:
        key_sort = list(key)
        key_sort.sort()

        length_list = len(message) // len(key)
        list_cut_words = []

        for _ in range(len(key)):
            list_cut_words.append([])
        index = 0
        counter = 1

        for symbol in message:
            if counter % length_list != 0:
                list_cut_words[index].append(symbol)
                counter += 1

            else:
                list_cut_words[index].append(symbol)
                index += 1
                counter = 1

        keys = {key_sort[symbol]: list_cut_words[symbol] for symbol in range(len(key_sort))}
        keys = {i: keys[i] for i in key if i in keys}

        index = 0

        for _ in range(length_list):
            for symbol_one in keys:
                final += keys[symbol_one][index]

            index += 1

    return final


def encrypt_decrypt(mode, message):
    if mode == 'E':
        message = stage_one(mode, message)
        message = stage_two(mode, message)

    else:
        message = stage_two(mode, message)
        message = stage_one(mode, message)

    return message


def main():
    crypt_mode = crypt_menu()

    print(encrypt_decrypt(crypt_mode, input_text))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your fractionation key is different from the one in Wikipedia's example: "A" should become "AD", not "AA", etc

Comment: ty! I will change the key dictionary then